# Django Admin: object is not JSON serializable error on Custom Field Sub-classing JSONField

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to de-normalize my Django Postgres database that backs a JSON API by storing certain objects in JSONFields:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

I extended the django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField field to serialize data into Python objects automatically. I'm doing this in order to encapsulate my logic around the objects and to enforce the structure of the objects stored in the JSONField. I'm following the Django documentation on custom model fields here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/

I'm able to store my objects in the custom JSONField and can retrieve them as native Python objects, however, I've broken the admin console. When I try to view one of my objects, i get this error:

```
TypeError: <core.fields.PostalAddress object at 0x7fdcfaade4e0> is not JSON serializable
```

I assume that the problem is that built-in json.dumps function doesn't play nicely with random objects, so I hope that there is some method I can override in my PostalAddress class to get it to play nice.

Here is my code, although this is a simple case of an address, I want to apply this pattern to more complicated and useful custom JSONField use cases, so I would like to see the serialized JSON in the admin console and be able to edit the text and save it.

fields.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class PostalAddress(object):
    def __init__(self, street='', city='', state='', postal_code=''):
        self.street = street
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.postal_code = postal_code

def deserialize_address(address_dict):
    return PostalAddress(**address_dict)

def get_empty_address():
    return PostalAddress()

class PostalAddressField(JSONField):
    description = "A postal address"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostalAddressField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return value
        if isinstance(value, PostalAddress):
            return json.dumps(value.__dict__)
        return value

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return deserialize_address(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, PostalAddress):
            return value
        if value is None:
            return value
        return deserialize_address(value)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from .fields import PostalAddressField, get_empty_address

class Person(models.Model):
    shipping_address = PostalAddressField(default = get_empty_address)
```

Full Trace:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:...

Django Version: 1.11.6
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['grappelli',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.postgres',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',...
]
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/grappelli/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 24
   <core.fields.PostalAddress object at 0x7f2c7fc085f8> is not JSON serializable   14 :                         {% if field.is_checkbox %}
   15 :                             <div class="c-1">&nbsp;</div>
   16 :                             <div class="c-2">
   17 :                                 {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag|prettylabel }}
   18 :                         {% else %}
   19 :                             <div class="c-1">{{ field.label_tag|prettylabel }}</div>
   20 :                             <div class="c-2">
   21 :                                 {% if field.is_readonly %}
   22 :                                     <div class="grp-readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
   23 :                                 {% else %}
   24 :                                      {{ field.field }} 
   25 :                                 {% endif %}
   26 :                         {% endif %}
   27 :                             {% if line.fields|length_is:'1' %}{{ line.errors }}{% endif %}
   28 :                             {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.field.errors }}{% endif %}
   29 :                             {% if field.field.help_text %}
   30 :                                 <p class="grp-help">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
   31 :                             {% endif %}
   32 :                         </div>
   33 :                     </div>
   34 :                 {% endfor %}


Traceback:

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  216.                 return template.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  209.                 return self._render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  411.         return strip_spaces_between_tags(self.nodelist.render(context).strip())

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  216.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  322.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1046.         return render_value_in_context(output, context)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_value_in_context
  1024.     value = force_text(value)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_text
  76.                     s = six.text_type(s)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/html.py" in <lambda>
  385.         klass.__str__ = lambda self: mark_safe(klass_str(self))

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in __str__
  40.             return self.as_widget() + self.as_hidden(only_initial=True)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  125.             value=self.value(),

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in value
  162.         return self.field.prepare_value(data)

File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/postgres/forms/jsonb.py" in prepare_value
  55.         return json.dumps(value)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  230.         return _default_encoder.encode(obj)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py" in encode
  198.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
  256.         return _iterencode(o, 0)

File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/encoder.py" in default
  179.         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/...
Exception Value: <core.fields.PostalAddress object at 0x7f2c7fc085f8> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? What you've posted above is just the last line.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks for looking! I added the full trace to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're having is that Django uses it's [`JSONField` form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/forms/jsonb/#JSONField) to try and deserialize the object in the admin - this fails because it just uses `json.dumps()` which cannot handle your `PostalAddress` object.

You have overridden the **model** field, but you will also need to override the **form** field used in the admin. The documentation describes how to [specify a custom form field for a model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field).

Something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.forms import JSONField 

# Define a new form field
class PostalAddressJSONField(JSONField):

    def prepare_value(self, value):
        # Here, deserialize the object in a way that works.
        # I've copied what you've done in your model field.
        return json.dumps(value.__dict__)
```

Then specify this new form field in your `PostalAddressField`:

```
class PostalAddressField(JSONField):

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'form_class': PostalAddressJSONField}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super().formfield(**defaults)
```

The `ModelAdmin` form should now use this custom form field, and be able to deserialize it correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the error rendering the admin page. I also had to override the validate() function on PostalAddressField. I'll update the question with the solution soon.

Comment: @mattydeeds How did you override validate () to be jsonfield valid ? did you skip the super() method ?

Comment: A good solution to skip lot of overriding methods and get a smaller code is to implement your own JSONEncoder that can serialize PostalAdress instances. Set it as default to your PostalAddressField on the PostalAddressField.encoder attribute